# Does NSIS have eval functionality?

Tags: scripting, nsis

For example, is there a way to do something along these lines?

```
Eval "MessageBox MB_OK 'Hello, World!'"
```

This is obviously a useless example, but I feel that such functionality would be useful.

Comment: Can you come up with a more useful example of what you are actually trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

The NSIS compiler (MakeNSIS) parses text files and writes out binary instructions into the generated setup. The setup application itself can only execute the instructions known at compile time.

Most instructions accept variables as their parameters so you can get different behavior. Here is a rather pointless example of that:

```
Page InstFiles

Function MaybeShowMessageBox
    IntCmp $0 0 skip
    MessageBox MB_OK "$1"
skip:
FunctionEnd

Section
StrCpy $0 1 ; Display it
StrCpy $1 "Hello World"
Call MaybeShowMessageBox

StrCpy $1 "Goodbye World"
Call MaybeShowMessageBox

StrCpy $0 0 ; Don't display it
Call MaybeShowMessageBox

StrCpy $0 0
StrCpy $2 "$WinDir" 1 ; Get the first character
StrCmp $2 "C" "" skipWinDirMessage
StrCpy $0 1
skipWinDirMessage:
StrCpy $1 "$WinDir is on drive C"
Call MaybeShowMessageBox
SectionEnd
```

You would ordinarily never write code like that. `IntFmt` is as close to Eval as you are going to get but it only operates on numbers:

```
ShowInstDetails show
Section
StrCpy $1 42

IntFmt $0 "%d" $1
DetailPrint "$1 as a number: $0"

IntFmt $0 "%#.4x" $1
DetailPrint "$1 as a hex number with a >= 4 width: $0"

IntFmt $0 "%c" $1
DetailPrint "$1 as a character: $0"
SectionEnd
```